What cohomology theory is used on moduli stacks in the context of Gromov Witten invariants
For example in chapter 25 of this book (https://www.claymath.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Mirror-Symmetry.pdf)
How are cohomology classes being pulled back along the evaluation maps?
The target is a variety, and the domain is a stack... how do we do algebraic topology on stacks?

I know almost nothing about this, but if you only need rational cohomology you can get away with constructions like the following: if a Deligne-Mumford stack can be presented as a quotient $X/G$ with $G$ finite and $X$ a variety then its rational cohomology should just be $H^i(X/G, \mathbb{Q}) \cong H^i(X, \mathbb{Q})^G$. I don't know if that's enough here.

Actually looks like earlier in the lectures such a presentation as a quotient is assumed - thanks!
